# Using fread() asynchronously

Tags: php, html, asynchronous, page-load-time

I have some code like the following:

```
$socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://my.domain.com:2082', $errno, $errstr, 1, STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT);
fwrite($socket, "\xfe\x01");
$data = fread($socket, 1024);
```

This code is executed when a HTML web page loads, the line where `fread` is used takes just over a second as can be seen:

```
1374008598.18 : Read begin
1374008599.75 : Read end
```

This incurs a great increase in page loading time, is there any way to execute the `fread()` command asynchronously. Considering that PHP is a server side language I'm not sure that it would be possible in this case, if not is there another solution to prevent this large increase in loading time as a result of `fread()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to improve this, is to return the html early and then use javascript to perform an AJAX request for another page which does the `fread()`..  You could display a progress bar until the operation has finished.

Btw, for sockets there is [`socket_read()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php)

Comment: Using an AJAX request to another page as you said worked perfectly. Thank you! +1 & ✔